# Meaning of "in the open"

Tags: word-in-context

What's the meaning of the expression "in the open" in the phrase below:

> This is partly because fear is uncommon and short-lived **in the open**.

The page where I found this sentence is: [dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/short-lived](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/short-lived). Before posting this question I did a Google search trying to find the full text or article so I could try to understand it by myself but I got nothing,

Does it have any figurative meaning in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need more context to be sure, but it probably just means "openly showing fear". The idea is that you rarely see people who are afraid, because when people are in public (in the open) their fear is rare and short-lived.